# Shutdown Linux Without Powerdown

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a `shutdown` on a Red Hat Linux 5.3 box where the machine will not power down at the end of the shutdown procedure. (Doing this allows me to cut power to the box and then get it to auto-boot once power has been restored.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shutdown -H now
```

Comment: Congrats on the 10K and the [triple laurel wreath](http://stackathlon.appspot.com/).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks. We'll see if it sticks around though (the question I broke 10k on was moved).

Comment: So it's "safe" to power-off the system when it is in single user mode?

Comment: If this brings the system into single-user mode then the documentation is wrong.

Comment: My mistake.  I saw a command prompt and assumed it was single-user mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some mild success thanks to studying the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/halt` script, creating a `/halt` file.  But the `/halt` file seems to get deleted upon booting.